# Math.random() applied as a percentage?

Tags: javascript, random, percentage

so I have this code that is giving me a random number for both top and left attribute of some images.

```
    var random1 = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 500);
var random2 = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 500);

$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#randomp').css('top', random1);
    $('#randomp').css('left', random2);

});
```

The problem is that I would be prefer to randomize a number between 1 and 100%. Is that possible?

Comment: That's the thing about copy and paste. It does not fix everything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1 + '%'
```

Answer (score 2):

Since [Math.random](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) returns number that is random, not less than `0` and less than `1`, you have just to multiply result by `99` instead of `500` to get a number beetween `1` and `100`%.

Finally, the code should be as follows:

```
var random1 = Math.round(Math.random() * 99) + 1;
var random2 = Math.round(Math.random() * 99) + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

This gives you a number between 0 and 100 (both included): 
`Math.floor(Math.random() * 101);`

1. Math random will give you a number between 0 (included) and 1 (excluded)
2. If you multiply that number with 101, it will give you a number between 0 (included) and 101 (excluded)
3. Math.floor will return the the largest integer less than or equal to the above number.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you want it rounded or not, so here's both:

```js
console.log( rando(1, 100) + "%" );
console.log( rando(1, 100, "float") + "%" );
```

```html
<script src="https://randojs.com/1.0.0.js"></script>
```

This uses [randojs.com](https://randojs.com) to make the randomness simple and readable. If you need to know more, check out the website.